# Laravel eloquent paginate in relation is not displayed in collection

Tags: laravel, pagination, eloquent

I want to page the relation articles. The correct number is displayed but not in the collection, for example "first page" or "to last".

```
$articles = Categories::where('slug', $categorie)->with(['articles' => function ($query) use ($default_count, $default_sort) {
            $query->orderBy('price', $default_sort)
            ->with('contents')
            ->paginate(2);
        }])->first();
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flipping it around so that `Article` is the top level:

```
$articles = Article::with('contents')
    ->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($categorie) {
        $query->where('slug', $categorie);
    })
    ->orderBy('price', $default_sort)
    ->paginate(2);
```

This assumes that you have the `category` relationship set up on `Article` as well.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want result some like that

```
    Article::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($categories) {
                $query->where('slug', $categories);
            })
    ->with('contents')
    ->orderBy('price', $default_sort)
    ->paginate(2);
```